# Unable to Terminate Django 2.1 Project Running on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with NGINX, UWSGI, and Celery

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, celery, uwsgi

I have a test project (a 'zombie' project) on the same server as the production version of my app. Both projects use Celery for background tasks, but they share the same RabbitMQ port. I noticed that some tasks from the production Celery instance were executed in the test environment. Attempting to resolve this, I tried to terminate the uwsgi process of the test project, but it was unsuccessful – the Django admin console for the test project remained accessible. Further attempts, such as renaming the project directory and restarting the server while ensuring the deletion of the relevant .pid file, also failed. I'm currently out of ideas and looking for help to resolve this issue.